# QTableWidget don't change style sheet after run application

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtstylesheets

I have some problem with style in Qt Creator. 
I added some style to QTableWidget and I noted difference after that in IDE.

```
QScrollBar:vertical {
     background: #fd966e;
}
```

[image]

[beforeRunApplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epW2p.png)

When I run my application style not loading to my Widget and I see this view.
[image]

[afterRunApplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPEl4.png)

What I am doing wrong ? Please help me.

Comment: How are you setting the style ?

Comment: @Marco I was paste this style in QT Creator in Property Manager

Comment: The syntax is fine. Did you run qmake before you compile?

Comment: @OnWhenReady Yes, I did. additionally I repated this step now, but result is the same.

Comment: I assume you saved, cleaned, run qmake, recompiled and checked that the right executable did run (you might have debug/release builds).

Comment: Please check if in the ui_xxx.h file of your widget the stylesheet was properly set.

Comment: @OnWhenReady I clean, run qmake and recompiled but is the same. In my .ui file style is the same, which I put in editor. Any others ideas?

Comment: Please check the "compiled" header file ui_xxx.h that was produced from qmake from your ui file for the stylesheet entry. Your example works perfectly fine for me. There must be another problem.

Comment: To be perfectly clear: the uic will do the translation of ui ... usually via qmake.

Comment: Which version of Qt do you use?

Comment: @OnWhenReady I use Desktop QT 5.5.0 MinGW. I found soultion which I described below.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem via added this code to constructor my window

```
QHeaderView * headerTemp = ui->listOfMovie->horizontalHeader();
scrollTemp->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("\n"
"QScrollBar:vertical {\n"
"background: #fd966e;\n"
"}"));
```

This works for me. Thank you for all advices.

Comment: This is a way to programmatically solve the problem. There are a few problems associated with your answer:
1. The code you provide does not show a meaningful answer. a) The first line is not necessary. b) Define *scrollTemp* (the vertical scrollbar). c) Don't use *fromUtf8* - instead use *QLatin1String("code")*
2. You provide a solution to set a stylesheet - a well known method to do that in Qt. It would be much more interesting for other people with a similar problem to know what the problem was. I assume the method to set it in the ui still does not work - but it should.